# append php form URL

Tags: php, forms, get

I currently built a simple form to GET request someones zipcode.

```html
<form action="http://example.com" method="get" target="_blank">
 
 <p>ZIPCODE</p>
 
 <input type="text" name="zip">
 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

When submitted it will be `http://example.com/?zip=ZIPCODE`

What I am looking to do it add an additional piece so it will be `http://example.com/?zip=234&country=usa`

I tried adding a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="country=usa"></input>` but this replaces `=` with `%3D` and adds `=` after it like so: `http://example.com/?zip=ZIPCODE&country%3Dusa=`

How can I easily append the URL with country=usa?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="country" value="usa" />`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="get" target="_blank">

    <p>ZIPCODE</p>

    <input type="text" name="zip">

    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="usa">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Wow, I guess I was asking the wrong question in google, thanks!