# Add string at the end position of particular text in a string

Tags: php, string

I need to append a text at the end position of the search term.

```
$baseStr = 'www.abc.com/cdf/?x=10';
$searchStr = 'www.abc.com/';
$insertStr = 'xxx/';
```

I need to insert `$insertStr` after **'www.abc.com/'** in `$baseStr`. I get only the start position using `strpos`.

Expected result:

```
$resultStr = 'www.abc.com/xxx/cdf/?x=10';
```

Edit:
Is it possible to find the end position of the search string and solve this?

Comment: start of `$baseStr` is fixed? I mean "www.abc.com"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [append php form URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944471/append-php-form-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` here:

```
$baseStr = 'www.abc.com/cdf/?x=10';
$searchStr = 'www.abc.com/';
$insertStr = 'xxx/';

$a = preg_replace('#'.$searchStr.'#', $searchStr.$insertStr, $baseStr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);

//Output: www.abc.com/xxx/cdf/?x=10
```

Or you can use `str_replace`:

```
$baseStr = 'www.abc.com/cdf/?x=10';
$searchStr = 'www.abc.com/';
$insertStr = 'xxx/';

$a = str_replace($searchStr, $searchStr.$insertStr, $baseStr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($a);

//Output: www.abc.com/xxx/cdf/?x=10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace `$searchStr` with `$searchStr` plus `$insertStr`

```
$baseStr = 'www.abc.com/cdf/?x=10';
$searchStr = 'www.abc.com/';
$insertStr = 'xxx/';
$resultStr = str_replace($searchStr, $searchStr.$insertStr, $baseStr);
echo $resultStr;
```

gives

```
www.abc.com/xxx/cdf/?x=10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

```
echo str_replace($searchStr, $searchStr.$insertStr,$baseStr);
```

Just replace your string it will search and replace for you.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9d2244c27fb8f27b250c9b58c363af63d33676ae).